# How can I remove css loaded with a script tag from my website along with the removal of that script tag?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, caching, webpack

This is an oddly specific problem that I can't find any information about anywhere.

I have a main React app that dynamically loads other react mini-apps. It does this via a component's `componentDidMount()` function, adding a script tag to the end of the document body with pure JavaScript, the src address of the tag proxies a request through to a web server to return a single bundled file which is the sub-app to load. When the component is unmounted the script tag is removed from the document's body and div root blanked out.

The mini-app needs to be loadable in a single bundle (no need to get into that here) and I achieve this by building the react app via a modified `npm run build` function which runs as below;

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "npm run build:sass && npm run build:react && npm run build:bundle",
    "build:react": "react-scripts build",
    "build:bundle": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "build:sass": "node-sass --precision=5 --indent-type=space --output-style=nested --indent-width=2 src/styles/Site.scss src/styles/Site.css"
  }
```

The bundle part of this command use the webpack.config.js file below;

```
const path = require("path")
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin")
const glob = require("glob")

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    "bundle.js": glob.sync("build/static/?(js|css)/*.?(js|css)").map(f => path.resolve(__dirname, f)),
  },
  output: {
    filename: "build/bundle.min.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [new UglifyJsPlugin()],
}
```

This in turn produces a single bundle.min.js file with all the scripts, node_modules and css from the mini-app which the main app loads via the component below.

```
export class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent<Props, object> {

    componentDidMount() {
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = "myScriptSrc";
        script.async = true;
        script.id = this.AppIdToScriptId();
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        document.getElementById("miniAppRoot").innerHTML = "";
        if (this.props.app) {
            document.getElementById(this.AppIdToScriptId()).remove();
        }
    }

    AppIdToScriptId = () => "d" + this.props.App.Id.replace("-", "");

    public render() {
        return (<div id="miniAppRoot" ></div>);
    }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

This all works great, the only issue I'm having here is the css loaded via the react mini-app bundled script persists even after I've removed the script tag and blanked the html root. Does anyone have any idea of why this is happening? I'm not sure if the webpack config is to blame, client-side caching or any other number of possibilities, any ideas of how to fix this?

Comment: This looks like browser cache problem to me

Comment: Like you said it could be any number of things.   You could try appending a query string to the end of your main css file to trick the browser into repainting/reloading the styles. Or try setting the mini apps display to display:none and display:<your display> to force the browser to repaint.  Another work around could be to override the styles by applying a unique selector to each app.   ie. #mini-app-1 .your-common-class {...},  #mini-app-2 .your-common-class {...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your webpack config you're using [style loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader). By default this is adding the styles as a tag in the dom.

If your main app loads css differently to how your sub apps are loading css, you should just be able to remove the anonymous style tags after unloading the script tag.

Otherwise, the style-loader does allow you to inject attributes into the generated style tags (or indeed load the styles in different ways). That should allow you to locate the sub-app style and strip it from the DOM.